# Function that should be targeting a specific open workbook seems to be using the activebook instead

Tags: excel, vba

This cell counting formula that I am using seems to be targeting the activesheet rather than the sheet that I clearly specified for it to use. Could anyone help me debug this? I'm relatively new to VBA. I was getting some unexplainable results from this formula, and after some testing it seems that whichever sheet I have as active is what this formula calculates for. That is not the intended result

```
        Dim totalRows as double
        totalRows = Workbooks("Mastersheet").Worksheets("masterBudgetSheet").range("A8:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count
```

Does specifying workbook and worksheet not target those two elements?

**ANSWERED: **
The targeting formula that I was using had an implicit call to the activesheet. This was fixed by ensuring that all the times that I called the "range" function that it included the exact sheet that I was trying to reference. (If none is included, it defaults to the active)

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`... there's an implicit `ActiveSheet` here.

Comment: @BigBen is there a way that I could modify this to do what it's suppose to do, which is count the number of cells with data in the sheet and book specified? Thank you for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to always reference your ranges, you forgot to reference the `Cells(Rows.Count...)`.

Also you could make your code more readable like this:

```
Dim totalRows As Double
With Workbooks("Mastersheet").Worksheets("masterBudgetSheet")
    totalRows = .Range("A8:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count
End with
```

This way, with the single use of the dot in front of your range, you are referencing the `With Workbooks("Mastersheet").Worksheets("masterBudgetSheet")` in between the `With` statement

Comment: If you really want to be nitpicky, you could add a period in front of the first `Rows.Count` too.

Comment: Yeah... I use it depending on the day... as long as we are not mixing xls with xlsx files should be fine though.

Comment: Well the real problem would be if the active sheet were a chart sheet... xls or xlsx isn't really relevant.

Comment: Guess we learn something new everyday! Thanks for that BigBen

Comment: @Damian Thanks for your answer post. What do you mean by I didn't reference the "Cells(Rows.Count...)"? Again, I'm a little bit new to VBA

Comment: @oXeru you did reference the  `.Range("A8:A" & *)` but inside it, you had another range: `Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` as you can see, there is no workbook and worksheet reference there. You should write all the reference all over again, or as in my answer use a `With` statement. It allows you to reference whatever you are using inside the `With` using the dot.

Comment: @Damian Ahhhh, I think I see what you're saying. When I did "Rows.Count", since I didn't specify a sheet, it just used active... I will mess around with the code and see if I can get it to target properly.

Comment: @oXeru in my answer it references correctly, you can try it.

Comment: @oXeru normally you want to qualify any `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns` calls with the worksheet and workbook.

Comment: @Damian that worked flawlessly. Thank you for the explanation. I mustve gotten lucky when I've used that same targeting formula in the past.

Comment: @BigBen Damian helped me get the targeting cleaned up. Thank you for your input as well.

Comment: @oXeru glad we could help. If the answer suits your needs, please consider to mark it as correct.